# How to create a time-lapse video from JPEG images using avconv?

Tags: avconv

I have a few hundreds of still images. The files are named according to the Canon convention - `IMG_2501.JPG, IMG_2502.JPG, IMG_2503.JPG, ...`.

I've tried:

```
% avconv -f image2 -i IMG_%04d.JPG avconv_out.avi

avconv version 0.8.9-6:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
built on Nov  9 2013 19:09:46 with gcc 4.8.1
IMG_%04d.JPG: No such file or directory
```

I guess that `IMG_%04d.JPG` is not found because `avconv` expects `IMG_0000.JPG, IMG_0001.JPG, ...`. I can create a symlink for that, but it's a really ugly hack.

How do I create a video from these still photos using `avconv` without renaming?

Comment: What about adding `avconv -start_number 2501 -f image2 -i ...`  ?

Comment: It will probably fail if a picture is missing from the sequence, which happens every now and then (I stop the camera, make a few calibration pictures, delete them and continue).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename them first

```
a=1
for i in *.JPG; do
  new=$(printf "%04d.JPG" ${a}) #04 pad to length of 4
  mv ${i} ${new}
  let a=a+1
done
```

Comment: A better approach would be to create links, which will keep the filenames the same (it matters to some people), in this case substitute `mv` for `ln`. You can then do the conversion and delete all the links.