# How can I create a video file from a set of jpg images?

Tags: 14.04, avconv

I am attempting to create a video file from a set of JPG images. I have adapted the instructions given in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269834/how-to-generate-a-mov-file-from-png-images) but have experienced some issues.

Firstly, not all of the required packages are available, but are replaced by libav-tools, which is already installed - so I think that's not an actual problem?

My files are named `image-NN.jpg` (NN being an integer) and I have used the command

```
avconv -i "image-%d.jpg" -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mov
```

as per the linked question, but this just gives a `No such file image-%d.jpg` error. I

I tried changing it to

```
avconv -i "image-*.jpg" -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mov
```

and this produces a video file of length 0:00 that appears to only contain one frame. (I am guessing that the `*` has used the first match, rather than every match).

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396442/how-to-create-a-time-lapse-video-from-jpeg-images-using-avconv) gives a slightly different way of formatting the file name, so I tried

```
avconv -i "image-%02d.jpg" -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mov
```

This produces a larger file, and makes a video that lasts for about 3 seconds (approx the length I was expecting) but it contains just the first frame.

Another answer on the first linked question suggests using ImageMagick, so I gave this a try

```
convert -delay 1 image-*.jpg output.mp4
```

But this produced an error

```
convert.im6: delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -mbd rd -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -i "%M%%d.jpg" "%u.%m" 2> "%Z"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1065.
```

The version of avconv is

```
carl@number1 ~/Scott's stop-motion/1 $ avconv -version
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
avconv 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
libavutil     52.  3. 0 / 52.  3. 0
libavcodec    54. 35. 0 / 54. 35. 0
libavformat   54. 20. 4 / 54. 20. 4
libavdevice   53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
libavfilter    3.  3. 0 /  3.  3. 0
libavresample  1.  0. 1 /  1.  0. 1
libswscale     2.  1. 1 /  2.  1. 1
```

Where am I going wrong, and what do I need to do?

**Additional:**
It was suggested that I list every file individually, so with a bit of Python I generated this

```
avconv -i image-01.jpg image-02.jpg image-03.jpg image-04.jpg image-05.jpg image-06.jpg image-07.jpg image-08.jpg image-09.jpg image-10.jpg image-11.jpg image-12.jpg image-13.jpg image-14.jpg image-15.jpg image-16.jpg image-17.jpg image-18.jpg image-19.jpg image-20.jpg image-21.jpg image-22.jpg image-23.jpg image-24.jpg image-25.jpg image-26.jpg image-27.jpg image-28.jpg image-29.jpg image-30.jpg image-31.jpg image-32.jpg image-33.jpg image-34.jpg image-35.jpg image-36.jpg image-37.jpg image-38.jpg image-39.jpg image-40.jpg image-41.jpg image-42.jpg image-43.jpg image-44.jpg image-45.jpg image-46.jpg image-47.jpg image-48.jpg image-49.jpg image-50.jpg image-51.jpg image-52.jpg image-53.jpg image-54.jpg image-55.jpg image-56.jpg image-57.jpg image-58.jpg image-59.jpg image-60.jpg image-61.jpg image-62.jpg image-63.jpg image-64.jpg image-65.jpg image-66.jpg image-67.jpg image-68.jpg image-69.jpg image-70.jpg image-71.jpg image-72.jpg image-73.jpg image-74.jpg image-75.jpg image-76.jpg image-77.jpg image-78.jpg image-79.jpg image-80.jpg image-81.jpg image-82.jpg image-83.jpg image-84.jpg image-85.jpg image-86.jpg image-87.jpg image-88.jpg  -r 25 -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mov
```

This had the same effect as previous - only the first frame is used.

**Additional:** [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50339/how-to-make-a-stop-motion-or-time-lapse-video-with-webcam/50355#comment851937_50355) has been suggested as a possible duplicate, but it relates to acquiring images using a webcam connected to a PC. This is not the issue I am having. I already have the photos; they were taken with an ordinary digital camera.

Comment: You could try just listing every single frame, instead of a `*` or a `%02d`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited that into the question.

Comment: Read this thread. It might help. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1538209

Comment: @CarlH that makes your question a subset of the linked one - it covers acquiring images *and* converting them.

Comment: @CarlH I agree that this question is not a duplicate of the linked question, no webcam involved here at all! I have nominated for reopening...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg`, which you can install with the command:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

This is the command all together:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i image-%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Let me break it down:

```
-framerate
```

is the number of frames (images) per second,

```
-i image-%05d.jpg
```

this determines the file name sequence it looks for. `image-` means all of the files start with this. The `d` indicates decimal integers, `5` is number of digits, the leading zero indicates that numbers requiring fewer digits will be filled, in the left, with zeroes so that every number contains exactly 5 digits. Thus the files it will detect are everything from `image-00000` to `image-99999`.

```
-c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p
```

`-c:v libx264` - the video codec is libx264 (H.264).

`-profile:v high` - use H.264 High Profile (advanced features, better quality).

`-crf 20` - constant quality mode, very high quality (lower numbers are higher quality, 18 is the smallest you would want to use).

`-pix_fmt yuv420p` - use YUV pixel format and 4:2:0 [Chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)

```
output.mp4
```

The file name (`output.mp4`)

Remember that `ffmpeg` needs a continuous sequence of images to load in. If it jumps from `image-00001` to `image-00003` it will stop.

If your images are named like this:

```
image-1
image-2
...
image-35
```

then change the `-i` part to `-i image-%00d`.

---

Update. Your edit says the pattern is `image-01.jpg` to `image-02.jpg`. That means you need the `image-%02d.jpg` pattern.

Comment: `-c:v libx264` — the video codec is libx264 ([H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC)). `-profile:v high` — use H.264 High Profile (advanced features, better quality). `-crf 20` — constant quality mode, very high quality (lower numbers are higher quality, 18 is the smallest you would want to use). `-pix_fmt yuv420p` — use [YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) pixel format and 4:2:0 [Chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)

Comment: Typo in your update: should be `image-%02d.jpg`, not `image-%20d.jpg`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Ubuntu uses an ffmpeg fork: avconv. So the command starts with avconv -framerate ...

Comment: How do you change the resolution with this? I tried the -s option but it just got ignored...

Comment: how about without a pattern?

Comment: @moeiscool what pattern?

Comment: You can also use `-pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'` if the file order presented by `ls` works for you.

Comment: If you get the error `width not divisible by 2 (2481x3508)`, add `-vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2"` after `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Comment: Resulting video was flipped both horizontally and vertically with respect to the original images. I adjusted the command to fix this. Moreover, I also scaled the video to width of 1920 while keeping the original aspect ratio `-vf vflip,hflip,scale=1920:-2,setsar=1:1`.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to waste your time with the file naming and order I would recommend to take a look into:

```
-pattern_type glob
```

Credits for this goes [this very comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478183/4424636) to [How to create a video from images with FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24961127/4424636)

It will also provide several examples.

Comment: To be more specific, use `-pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg'` if the file order presented by `ls` works for you.